# Is it to problem to handle with arxml files as xml files to do a parsing

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing, xls, autosar

I am editing a python script to parse an `arxml` file and to put the data extracted in an `xls` file.

I want to work with beautifulsoup module but I don't find all information about the functions that I can use it.

I tried with the module `xml.etree.ElementTree` and it seems working.

I want to know if it can be a problem to deal with `arxml` file as an `xml` file

Answer (score 1):

ARXML is 100% plain XML. You can load an ARXML file into any tool that accepts XML content. But not every tool that accepts XML content is capable of understanding the semantics (i.e. a serialized AUTOSAR model) of an ARXML file.

This is the major reason why the file extension .arxml is typically used for ARXML files: the creation of an association between files that contain ARXML content and the tools that can properly handle it becomes easier to achieve.